# catkin: move/remove package and workspace

Tags: ros, catkin, package

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I have a catkin workspace containing some catkin packages. They were created using catkin_init_workspace and catkin_create_pkg commands respectively.

I want to move them all in another directory but I didn't find any tutorial about it. Is there something I have to do before that? Can I simply *mv -r* this workspace directory?

I have some doubts because using *rosrun* ROS I can find my packages everywhere and it doesn't ask me for paths, so I thought it could be possible only with some environment settings. I'm cautios about moving workspace, that's why I'm asking here :)

I'm using ROS Groovy and Ubuntu 12.04

So, briefly my questione are:

- How to move packages into another workspace?
- How to move the entire workspace with all its packages?
- How to remove a package?
- How to remove an entire workspace?

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/105576/catkin:-move/remove-package-and-workspace/) by [eds](https://answers.ros.org/users/9241/eds/) on ROS Answers with karma: 101 on 2013-11-27

Post score: 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For removing packages: Just delete them (and rebuild). They'll be gone.

For removing a workspace: Just delete it (there are no other traces).

When moving packages or workspaces to another directory/workspace you should probably clean the build completely and rebuild.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2013-11-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 15

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [shawnysh](https://answers.ros.org/users/28421/shawnysh/) on 2017-05-30**:
what if my package is build from source(clone from github and catkin_make)? Is it the same way as debian install is?

**Comment by [matkok](https://answers.ros.org/users/30173/matkok/) on 2019-04-15**:
sudo apt-get remove ros-$Distro-$package_name

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When I removed the source folder of a package, an error happened in `catkin build` command for the package.
So I used the following command and the build succeeded:

> catkin clean --dependents PKGNAME

---

Originally posted by [bigbellmercy](https://answers.ros.org/users/40244/bigbellmercy/) with karma: 86 on 2021-09-02

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1